# Mac OS java home ambiguty

Tags: java, macos

Please see these 3 commands and their outcomes in MacOS:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home

Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Why does the first one return 1.8? What exactly is /libexec/java_home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koray,

As per the [Oracle docs](https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/glossary_for_jdk_builds)...

JAVA_HOME is just an environment variable used to trigger the 'java' found in your PATH to use a different JDK image. Unfortunately, not all 'java' startup scripts obey this env variable. It's also used by many java tool startup scripts to determine what 'java' to run, bypassing the 'java' found in the PATH setting. Setting this variable during a JDK build is a bad idea, don't do it.

I use Eclipse myself, and don't have a JAVA_HOME env variable defined, here is my output running the same commands.

```
brandon@brandons-mbp ~
$ /usr/libexec/java_home 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home

brandon@brandons-mbp ~
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

brandon@brandons-mbp ~
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Not sure why you have two different versions but did you try updating your JDK recently? Maybe when you upgraded it failed to launch a script to update your $JAVA_HOME.

Here's the [instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html) for installing JDK and setting JAVA_HOME on *nix based OSes.

Let me know if that helps I can help you dig deeper if need be.

Comment: Ah, so that is the problem. The first triggers the java in PATH.. Got it.. But why would you say setting JAVA_HOME variable is bad?

Comment: Oh that was literally directly from the Oracle Docs page :) 

I have a sysadmin background though so I generally warn users to be very careful when playing around with any sorts of env variables on both windows and OS X!

Comment: Ok thanks.. I have explicitly set JAVA_HOME to 1.7 and I have both 1.7 and 1.8 installed. Probably 1.8 made itself to /usr/libexec/java_home (I still do not understand what this command is actually, but it is ok..) and 1.7 remains only in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home, btw 1.8 is in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home